# Combining both time and date string to create a single DateTime object

Tags: c#, datetime

I have found many brilliant solutions on converting time string to a DateTime object as well as converting date string to a DateTime object. What I have not found is something that does both at the same time.

An example of the two strings are:

1/10/2017

12:00 AM

This is my attempt at it.

C#

```
var start = model.PublishDate;
var time = model.PublishTime;

if(time.Length == 7)
{
    time = "0" + time;
}
var dateTimeString = start + " " + time;

dbSectionProps.PublishDate = DateTime.ParseExact(dateTimeString, 
       new string[] { "M/d/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", "M/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", "MM/d/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt" }, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None);
```

However it throws an error. Any suggestions would be wonderful. Thanks!

Comment: the error has a message associated with it.  what are the words?

Comment: Probably you need to add a space between the start and time strings

Comment: Also it seems that your time variable is adjusted to a length of 8 chars. Where is the tt part required by the ParseExact?

Comment: Exception thrown: 'System.FormatException' in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Comment: Adding a space did not work

Comment: You need the PM AM or remove the tt from the formats. (and in this latter case your time values should be 0-24 with the format for hours changed to HH)

Comment: I have seen the tt referenced in other examples. Believe it was necessary to include an AM or PM

Comment: It is easy to test. Just remove the tt from those format strings

Comment: I removed the tt. Same exception

Comment: Can you write an example of your dateTimeString?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe let the framework do the work for you.  Sample:

```
string dateString = "1/12/2017";
string timeString = "10:55:00 pm";

var d = DateTime.Parse(dateString).Date;
var t = DateTime.Parse(timeString).TimeOfDay;
DateTime sum = d.Add(t);

Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}\r\n{1}\r\n{2:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}", d, t, sum));
```

Comment: This looks very promising. I am going to try! Will let you know if it works

Answer (score 3):

After fixing the missing space between the two strings, you have another problem. The string produced doesn't contain the PM or AM specification while the format strings supplied to DateTime.ParseExact require the presence of these characters.

You can remove this requirement from your formats

```
string[] formats = new string[] 
{
    "M/d/yyyy hh:mm:ss", 
    "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss", 
    "M/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss", 
    "MM/d/yyyy hh:mm:ss"
};
dbSectionProps.PublishDate = DateTime.ParseExact(dateTimeString, 
     formats, CultureInfo.InvarianCulture, DateTimeStyles.None);
```

But this will not work if your time part contains the hours specified as 0-23 because [the format hh cannot work with values bigger than 12](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_20). So you need to change the hh to HH

**EDIT**
After seeing your last edit, I think that the correct formats for a string

```
1/10/2017 12:00 AM
```

will be without the seconds specifier and with the tt again

```
string[] formats = new string[] 
{
    "M/d/yyyy hh:mm tt", 
    "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt", 
    "M/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt", 
    "MM/d/yyyy hh:mm tt"
};
```

Comment: I really appreciate the insight! The hh is correct in my case and I was actually hoping to include the two letter characters.

Comment: However I am going to remove the characters and insert your example into mine and see if it runs. Thanks again!!!

Comment: Hope it works. It's time to leave for me. Good night

Comment: Just seen your edit. That strings is missing of the seconds part. Now you need to remove the ss (and add again the tt) if you want the formats to match the input.